# Modify appSettings in the custom config file which is referenced via 'file' attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, appsettings

In `appSettings` section of Web.config  a `file` attribute is used referencing a custom config file. The goal is to have possibility to modify some app-settings in the custom config without causing the application to be restarted.

> Web.config

```
<appSettings file="CustomAppSettings.config">
    <add key="key1" value="val2" />
</appSettings>
```

> CustomAppSettings.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
    <add key="customKey1" value="custVal2"/>
</appSettings>
```

The following code does not work. It saves the value to *Web.config* but expected is to save it to the *CustomAppSettings.config* because so it will not restart the application ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228154(v=vs.100).aspx)).

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value.ToString();
configuration.Save();
```

This does not work as well.

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/CustomAppSettings.config");
```

What am I doing wrong? Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @vhinn terrible no, I didn't :(.

Comment: see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **configSource** instead of **file**.

```
<appSettings configSource="CustomAppSettings.config" />
```

use **ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal** on saving.

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value.ToString();
configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```